# Kendo grid data editable based on condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo Grid in my MVC project.
Here I am trying to set `Editable to false` for particular condition which is not working anymore::

I want field editable if its ID value is greater than 0

like::

```
 .Model(model =>
                                {
                                    model.Id(p => p.AirlineName);
                                    if (!(model.Field(x=>x.SegmentID)>0))
                                    {
                                        model.Field(x => x.SegmentClass).Editable(false);
                                    }
                                }
                        )
```